# Rotating a tablayout 90 degree

Tags: android, rotation, android-viewpager

i have tablayout with viewpager with this code:

```
     <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:tabGravity="fill"
        app:tabMode="scrollable" />


    <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tabs"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
```

java code:

```
 class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>(); // this line can cause crashes
        private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

        public void setTabText(int position, String text) {
            mFragmentTitleList.set(position, text);
        }

        public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
            super(manager);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return mFragmentList.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mFragmentList.size();
        }

        public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
            mFragmentList.add(fragment); // this line can cause crashes
            mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
        }
    }


  viewPagerAdapter = new

                ViewPagerAdapter(getActivity().

                getSupportFragmentManager());

        viewPagerAdapter.addFragment(myFragment, "tag"); // `myFragment` should be created inside `FragmentPagerAdapter.getItem()`
        viewpager.setAdapter(viewPagerAdapter);

        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewpager);
```

that code make's this layout:  tablayout is above and the fragments is below of that
[image]

and now i need a rotated tablayout like this picture:
(tablayout is right of page and viewpager is left of that)

how can i rotate this tablayout?
[image]

Answer (score -1):

try to use this

```
app:tabMode="fixed"
```

rather then

```
app:tabMode="scrollable"
```